# Characteristic function of composite channels

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, quantum-optics

For single-mode Gaussian channels $\mathcal C$, it holds that $\mathcal C = \mathcal A_G\circ L_\eta$, where $A_G$ is an amplifier channel described by the action $$\chi_{\rho'}(\xi)=\chi_\rho(\sqrt G\ \xi)e^{-(G-1)\frac{|\xi|^2}{2}}$$ on the characteristic function $\chi_{\rho}(\xi)=\text{Tr}\rho D_\xi$, where $D_\xi$ is the usual displacement operator, and likewise $L_\eta$ is a lossy channel described by the action $$\chi_{\rho'}(\xi)=\chi_\rho(\sqrt \eta\ \xi)e^{-(1-\eta)\frac{|\xi|^2}{2}}.$$
This is going to be somewhat of a dumb question, but here I go anyway, since I never work with this formalism and I want to be completely sure of this: can I then conclude that the action of $\mathcal C$ is defined by the transformation
$$\chi_{\rho'}(\xi)=\chi_\rho(\sqrt{G\eta}\ \xi)e^{-(1-\eta)\frac{G|\xi|^2}{2}-(G-1)\frac{|\xi|^2}{2}} $$ and that more generally, the characteristic function behaves intuitively under channel composition?

Comment: You may have more luck posting this in the quantum computing stack exchange, FYI.